# How can humans settle on a pulsar planet?

Tags: technology, aliens, civilization

I'm writing a sci fi adventure where my protagonists must go to an exotic planet which is orbiting around a magnetar, a neutron star emitting extremely powerful magnetic field and shooting powerful X rays into space from the poles. The pulsar planet is thrice as massive as Earth but totally barren and the air is thin and poisonous but surprisingly alien civilization somehow managed to establish a colony on the planet for thousands of years. My question is what kind of technology would enable a human being to survive living on the pulsar planet? (The technology should be limited to type 2 civilization and no FTL!)

Comment: If I remember correctly, neutron stars (And magnetars) create absolutely lethal levels of both particle and electromagnetic radiation. I can't find the source, but I remember reading somewhere that any planet near a neutron star would be a radiation-blasted hellscape with its atmosphere and organic-chemistry scoured away by solar winds.

Comment: @UIDAlexD: not wrong that's why I need your advice/expertise on this issue.

Comment: @UIDAlexD - that was my understanding too, regardless of whether the radiation ray bursts emitting from the poles are pointing at the planet or not.  But hey there's an alien civilization there already.  So why not.  Just wear SPF 10,000 sunscreen.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shot in the dark:  When faced with an inhospitable environment, we can either change the environment or enclose ourselves in a bit of our own.

As for the barren soil and poisonous air, an initial colony would be established in some kind of self-contained habitat.  Everything would be grown hydroponically.  (Basically, you can just land the ship you arrived in.)  Eventually you could terraform if you bring in more equipment and also deal with the aliens who were there first.

As for the magnetic field from the magnetar, you will want magnetic shielding.  If a Type II civilization can build a dyson sphere then it can also build shielding around the planet.  But if we want to start small, you could just shield the ship you arrived in as well as any vehicles you travel around in.

Either method could involve passive and active shielding.  Magnetars (and their magnetic fields) rotate rapidly, about once every second to ten seconds.  Surface flares are normal and this affects the magnetic field too.  With such rapid, inconstant changes in magnetic field strength, you would probably opt for some kind of active monitoring and countering system, basically like noise cancelling headphones, but with magnetic fields instead of sound waves.  Again, you could either build a planetary system or just give everyone a "magnetic umbrella."

EDIT RE: RADIATION
Also, you will need shielding from radiation.  Astronauts in the ISS are pretty shielded but have to hide in a safe room during some solar flares.  But again, if you can build a Dyson sphere, you probably have access to a lot of radiative shielding material, which you either build around the planet, or the star, or just the habitat.

EDIT RE: GRAVITY
Also, you will need like DARPA exo suits, or a lot of steriods, 'cos people cannot walk around with three times their body weight.  At least I can't.  At least not right away.

Comment: You **_cannot_** shield something from electric/magnetic/gravitational field. If scientists ever discover such a method, we would be able to travel anywhere in the universe without any fuel at all and it will break the law of conservation of energy. +rep for a nice effort :)

Comment: You definitely *can* shield something from electric field (Faraday cage), from magnetic field (iron plate) or from electromagnetic field AKA light (opaque material). You *cannot* quite reasonably shield something from hard γ, unless you use tons of material, and you definitely *cannot* shield something from gravity, that's true.

Comment: Yeah, I though active and passive magnetic shielding actually exist already.  http://www.emfservices.com/afcs.htm   As for the gamma radiation, my understanding is that these are emitted in a columnated beam extending from the poles, and thus an planet in orbit would not be hit. Most planets orbit along the same accretion disc that formed the entire star/planet system, which would be along the equator of the star not the pole. Though considering the star went nova, I suppose the star could have a new axis of spin, and of course it's a minor miracle that the planet exists at all in any orbit.

Answer (score 1):

A type K-Ⅱ civilization would have technology like **superconductors** that will be transformative.

It will be easy to block magnetic fields and electric fields using a superconductive skin, as they already do for scientific instruments and other sensitive devices.

The [pulsar planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar_planet) is made up of dense elements, making it easier and more suitable to shield from radiation by simply digging underground.  Looking for a reference, I notice that this is not universal; *one kind* of pulsar planet forms from the disbris disk after a supernova and is much like other planet formation except that the composition of the disk is heavy elements.

Digging underground when the ground is made of metal will in and of itself protect from electric fields at a reasonable depth, without needing to be “super”.  But [superconductors will allow absolute shielding of magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect): it will cause magnetic fields to set up an electric current in the perfect conductor that itself produces another magnetic field that exactly cancels the original.

[image: expell magnetic field]

Answer (score 1):

Current day Earth tech is enough:  Dig in.  You don't have to go very deep down to shield against everything the pulsar will throw at you so long as you are far enough out.  If the planet is too close in (you referred to the atmosphere as thin and toxic, you didn't specify bitterly cold) the tides become a serious problem.  (If you're close enough in not to freeze the tides become very nasty.  We're not talking just water movement, but the ground itself going up and down as we see on some moons of Jupiter.)  A tidally locked world avoids the problems with the tide but means a permanent night side that will freeze out the atmosphere and thus is incompatible with your description.

Also, oxygen is reactive.  The presence of free oxygen means there's something (almost certainly life) around generating it.  You described the atmosphere as toxic, not as anoxic.  Where is that oxygen coming from?